# Angular chained requests with GitHub API

Tags: angularjs, github, chaining

Playing around with Angular and GitHub API I'd like to get the 100 latest commits from my starred repos. It looks like I need to chain requests and iterate over my repos and then limit to the most recent. Not sure how though with Angular parallel and response manipulation.

So far I can return my starred repos through $http. Any idea?

```
app.service('apiService', [ "$http", ($http) ->
  factory  = {}

  base_url = "https://api.github.com/"
  gh_user  = "xxxx"

  factory.getCommits = ->
    $http(
      method: "GET"
      url: base_url + "users/#{gh_user}/starred"
      headers:
        Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
    )

  factory
])
```

Comment: Assuming the GH API doesn't allow you to do the limiting/sorting somehow you can make use of angular filters like limiteTo and orderBy keep in mind that the order in which you apply these will have an effect so generally you want to first do any regular filtering, then order by, then limit.

Comment: My problem is how to iterate over arrays after several API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an angular-github-adapter a while ago. It wraps the github API in promised based `$http` calls, maybe this is helpful for you: https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-github-adapter